# git ssh doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh

I have done what the document said, and when I type  `ssh -T git@github.com`, 
it will show

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[192.30.252.149]:443
' to the list of known hosts.
Hi fifiteen82726! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
 shell access.
```

However, when I want to push something to `github`, it still require my `username` and `password`. Why?

### Update

Here is my `.git/config`

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/fifiteen82726/MFA.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: It might be that your current repository is directed to use https. What is written in your `.git/config`?

Comment: I didn't get what you said, but I have updated my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using HTTPS protocol instead of SSH.

Change url of the repository to `git@github.com:fifiteen82726/MFA.git`

Ex. command `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:fifiteen82726/MFA.git`

Here's the GitHub help page describing how to get addresses for different protocols https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/